# Gibt es Rotwelsch mittlerweile auch in der gehobenen Sprache?

Tags: etymology, dialect, regional, colloquial

Als [Rotwelsch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotwelsch) wird schon im Mittelalter die Geheimsprache der Gauner und Bettler bezeichnet. Mittlerweile sind viele Ausdrücke des Rotwelschen fester Bestandteil der deutschen Umgangssprache geworden:

> Erika beklagt sich über ihre ungezogenen Kinder: "Es ist so verdächtig ruhig. Ich habe *Bammel*, dass die *Blagen* in ihrem *Kabuff* wieder etwas *ausbaldowern*."
>
> "Mann, habe ich einen *Kohldampf*!"

Bei einigen Wörtern ist ihre Herkunft aus dem Rotwelschen kaum noch bekannt:

> "Durch das viele *Schwänzen* hat Kevin sein Zeugnis *vermasselt*."
>
> "Die Rentenreform ist eine *Mogel*packung."
>
> "Viele ältere Mitbürger nehmen Anstoß an *schmusenden* Paaren in der Öffentlichkeit."

Ist es nur mein persönlicher Eindruck, oder sind viele Begriffe des Rotwelschen mittlerweile auch in der gehobenen Sprache zu finden? Gibt es in ihrer Verwendung regionale Unterschiede?

Comment: Mit deinen Beispielen hast du deine Frage ja schon nahezu beantwortet. Bei Wörtern wie Blagen, Kabuff oder schmusen war mir die derartige Herkunft nicht bewusst. Das ist die Sprache meiner Großeltern…

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Überfliegt man z.B. unter http://www.wispor.de/wpx-rotw.htm die Begriffe und findet solche wie *Bammel*, *Kabuff*, *Knast*, *koscher* und *meschugge*, dann verstärkt sich zwar der Eindruck einer Durchdringung des gegenwärtigen Deutschen, aber ein leicht unsicheres Gefühl bleibt: ist dies wirklich *Hochsprache*?

Glücklicherweise gibt es eine **Dissertation von Jasmina Cirkic** (die hoffentlich kein Schmee ist, weil z.B. ohne Kennzeichnung aus anderen Quellen kiebitzt wurde), in der exakt dieses Thema ausbaldowert wird (auch die Nebenfrage nach den regionalen Unterschieden wird behandelt) und die frei downloadbar ist: http://ubm.opus.hbz-nrw.de/volltexte/2008/1589/.

Diese "untersucht das Vorkommen rotwelschen Vokabulars in der deutschen Gegenwartssprache", und im Fazit lesen wir: das "Rotwelsche ist heutzutage nicht mehr auf das kriminelle Milieu und die Randgruppen der Gesellschaft beschränkt. Die Auswertungen haben gezeigt, dass einzelne Wörter aus dem Rotwelschen alltäglich in der Umgangssprache sowie in Texten der Massenmedien verwendet werden."

Wenn "Massenmedien" nicht nur den Springer-Ramsch meint (oder vergleichbares Geseire, mit dem wir gepisackt und eingeseift werden sollen und dessen Produzenten allesamt Gauner und Ganoven sind, die nur um der Moneten willen malochen), wäre dies ein duftes Indiz für Hochsprache.