# What's the meaning of "Er hat mit ihr geschäckert"?

Tags: meaning, translation, verb

Can someone translate this into English:

> Er hat mit ihr geschäkert.

The verb "schäckern" has no entry in [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/) .

**UPDATE**

The correct spelling is **schäkern** which you can find in most dictionaries.

Comment: Shake it, babe! If you write it correctly with one 'k', you'll find it at dict.leo.org as `to flirt with so.` . As `schäckern`, you would need to spell it like `meckern`, while it is longer, like `Apothekern`: "Wir schäkern, mit den Apothjekern".

Comment: I vote to close because when [I tried searching "schäckern"](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=sch%C3%A4ckern) I didn't find it as you said, but the spelling was suggested.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the correct spelling is "[geschäkert](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Gesch%C3%A4ker&failed_kw=gesch%C3%A4kert)":

> VERB: schäkern | schäkerte | geschäkert

So, the meaning of the sentence should be:

> He was flirting with her.

Answer (score 19):

It's not "schäckern", it's schäkern, without the 'c'. The origin of that word is:

> "Rotwelsch or Gaunersprache, [...] a secret language, a cant or thieves' argot, spoken by covert groups primarily in southern Germany and Switzerland." <sub>([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotwelsch), see also [Gibt es Rotwelsch mittlerweile auch in der gehobenen Sprache?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/gibt-es-rotwelsch-mittlerweile-auch-in-der-gehobenen-sprache))</sub>

I believe it used to be more common a few decades ago (that's  not scientific, but a childhood memory).

With the 'c' gone, you find it in [leo.org](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/sch%C3%A4kern.html): my favourite translation here would be "to dally with sb.", but all others are fine.