# What is the origin of the prefix "schwarz-"?

Tags: etymology, prefix

In German the prefix *"schwarz-"* is often used to depict something illegal like:

> Schwarzfahrer
>   Schwarzarbeit
>   Schwarzgeld

Is there any specific origin for using *black* in this context?

Comment: Nice question, since I think "Rot" is more suitable in this context than "Schwarz".

Comment: For Schwarzarbeit and Schwarzgeld ngram shows usage as early as 1845. Anyone knows a way to find the sources from that information?

Comment: Da fehlt doch noch ein wichtiges "schwarz", nämlich das "Schwarzbrennen".

Comment: Usually it is used when the illegal activity doesn't cause direct damage but leads to lost revenues and is thus widely regarded as a trivial offense.  BTW, I would consider "schwarz kopieren" a much more appropriate term than "raubkopieren" to describe illegal copying of software or music.

Comment: +1 für Schwarzbrennen @bernd_k :)

Comment: "Black," the English equivalent, is used in a similar way in English.

Comment: "Schwarzgeld" fließt in "schwarze Kassen".

Comment: _Schwarzmarkt_, _Schwarzbuch_, (_anschwärzen_, _schwarzmalen_)

Comment: Ich habe noch "schwarz schlachten" im Angebot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Grimms Wörterbuch](http://www.verstecken.uni-trier.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GS20701&hitlist=&patternlist=&mode=Gliederung) says this:

> g) von geschmuggelten waaren sagt man: schwarz herein (über die grenze) kommen, vielleicht weil man bei nacht zu schmuggeln pflegt (vgl. DWB schwärze, 'nacht' in der gaunersprache, s. dies), so dasz schwarz hier gewissermaszen prädicativisch im sinne von 'dunkel, in der dunkelheit' stände, oder weil die schmuggler sich das gesicht schwärzen, um sich unkenntlich zu machen. Schm.2 2, 649. vgl. schwärzen.

Comment: Also ist *"schwarz-"* noch so ein etablierter Begriff aus dem [Rotwelsch](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2530/23). Interessant!

Comment: Schwarzarbeit sieht man aber eher am Wochenende, und Schwarzfahrer sind auch keine lichtscheuen Elemente - allenfalls blinde Passagiere.