# Woher kommt die Bezeichnung "Stift" für Lehrjungen?

Tags: etymology

Die Bezeichnung **Stift** für Lehrjungen ist mir noch geläufig, obwohl man heute wohl eher **Azubi** sagt.

Siehe [Auszubildender auf dieser Begriffsklärung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stift).

Wer kann etwas zur Herkunft des Begriffes sagen?

Comment: Aus meiner Schulzeit ([HTL](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6here_Technische_Lehranstalt) in Oberösterreich) kenne ich den Begriff "Stift" auch für die Erst-Klässler.

Comment: Vgl. "Jung-Spunt, ein junger Spunt".

Answer (score 13):

Im ersten Moment dachte ich an einen Zusammenhang, dass der Lehrling den Stift halten müsse oder mitschreiben müsse. Tatsächlich scheint es diesen Zusammenhang aber so nicht zu geben, im Grimm findet sich dazu:

> stift, m.; wort unbekannter herkunft, vermutlich übertragen von stift für etwas kleines geringwertiges, unbedeutendes; aus der gaunersprache übernommen, vgl. Grolman spitzbubenspr. (1822) 69, Avé-Lallemant 4, 206, 219, 610; im sinne 'anfänger, lehrling',
>
> besonders 'kaufmannslehrling', 'jüngster, kleinster einer gemeinschaft' scherzhaft und geringschätzig in der umgangssprache gebraucht: da kriegte ich einen heillosen schreck und muszte mich etwas besinnen, und der stift sah mich an, was ich zu der neuigkeit sagen wollte denkw. u. erinn. e. arbeiters (1903) 222 Göhre;
>
> ein stift halt meinen hut,
>
> den mantel bringt der ober
>
> J. Weinheber Wien wörtlich (1935) 91;

Comment: Hat es vielleicht auch mit `stiften gehen` zu tun - jetzt nicht die Konrad-Adenauer-Stiftung meinend.

Comment: Ich habe den gesamten Eintrag aus dem Grimm zitiert. Ich fürchte, mehr ist darüber nicht bekannt. Der Duden bietet auch nur "etwas Kleines, Geringwertiges" als Bedeutungsherkunft, wie es auch im Grimm auftaucht. Zum "Stiften gehen" findet sich noch im Grimm: *die herkunft ist dunkel, vielleicht stammt das wort wie stift ursprünglich aus der gaunersprache.*

Comment: Schon wieder [Rotwelsch](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2530/23) - vielleicht. :)

Comment: Ich kenne folgende Erklärung aus dem technischen Bereich:

> Ein [Stift][1] ist eine Niete ohne Kopf.

Es ist also eine geringschätzende bis humorvolle Bezeichnung, die möglicherweise auf einen geringen Wissensstand ("Niete": erfolgloser Mensch) und eine geringe Konzentrationsfähigkeit ("ohne Kopf") bei einigen Auszubildenden anspielt.

  [1]: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stift_(Maschinenbau)

Comment: Vielleicht weit hergeholt: Der Imker bezeichnet Bieneneier und -Larven als "Stifte" - Man könnte annehmen, dass daher die Ableitung für den "Nachwuchs" kommt. Andrerseits könnte der Begriff auch vom *zu etwas Anstiften* kommen.