# Welchen Ursprung hat das Wort "Pustekuchen"?

Tags: etymology

Laut Wikipedia gibt es zwei Erklärungsversuche für *[Pustekuchen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pustekuchen)*:

1. Es stammt aus einer abgewandelten Form des jiddischen Ausdrucks: *Ja cochem, aber nicht lamdon* ("Zwar gerissen, aber kein Gelehrter" oder "Schlau, aber nicht schlau genug"). Daraus soll sich *Ja Kuchen, nicht London* entwickelt haben (ähnlich wie *[Hechtsuppe](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/es_zieht_wie_Hechtsuppe)*). Daraus wiederum *Pustekuchen*.
2. Goethes Versuch, seinen Widersacher *Johann Pustkuchen* lächerlich zu machen.

Was mir an der zweiten Erklärung nicht gefällt, ist der Umstand, dass [Googles Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Pustekuchen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3) keinen Nachweis des Wortes zu Goethes Lebzeiten vorzuweisen hat. Nun sollte man allerdings Ngram auch nicht überbewerten.

Weiß jemand mehr über den Ursprung? Ist die Erklärung aus dem Jiddischen plausibel? Im Wikipedia-Artikel klingt sie ein wenig an den Haaren herbeigezogen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wie viele umgangssprachlichen Wörter entstammt auch ***"Pustekuchen"*** aus dem [Rotwelsch](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2530/23), der ehemaligen Geheimsprache von Gaunern und Ganoven.

> Wie auch immer diese Sondersprachen genannt werden, sie haben Spuren hinterlassen in der Alltagssprache aller Rheinländer, ohne dass ihnen dies jedoch bewusst ist. Wer weiß schon, dass er, wenn er von malochen, schnorren, Knast, zappenduster, betucht, **Pustekuchen**, Pleite oder Kohldampf spricht oder Redewendungen wie es zieht wie Hechtsuppe, unter aller Sau oder zeigen, was eine Harke ist benutzt, sich ehemals gaunersprachlichen Wortinventars bedient, denn um nichts anderes handelt es sich hier.<sup>[LVR](http://www.rheinische-landeskunde.lvr.de/sprache/sprachen/geheimsprachen.htm)</sup>
>
> Auch der Ausdruck "Pustekuchen" habe weder mit Pusten noch mit Backwaren etwas zu tun. In dem Wort steckten vielmehr die hebräischen Worte ***"poschut"*** – wenig und ***"kochem"*** - was klug oder gewieft bedeute.<sup>[SWRinfo](http://www.swr.de/contra/-/id=7612/nid=7612/did=7539890/mpni4k/index.html)</sup>

Comment: Fazit: [Quittiert man eine Äußerung mit dem Ausruf "Pustekuchen!", so qualifiziert man sie als "wenig klug", unklug oder dumm.](http://www.abendblatt.de/ratgeber/wissen/article586518/Sprachliche-Koestlichkeiten.html)

Comment: Und wie kommt das hebräische ins Rotwelsch?

Comment: @user unknown: Einfach mal in [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotwelsch#Sozialer_Kontext) nachschlagen. "Der hohe Anteil an jiddischen und hebräischen Lehnwörtern erklärt sich dadurch, dass Juden von den meisten landwirtschaftlichen und bürgerlichen Berufen ausgeschlossen waren und darum bis ins 19. Jahrhundert einen bedeutenden Teil der Träger mobiler Berufe, besonders der fahrenden Händler und Hausierer, stellten."

Answer (score 5):

*Pust* (from the Slavic) means empty or hollow and *chochem* (not kochem) is a wise man: among the Karaites, the *chochem* was their rabbi. A *chochmeh* (note the ending) is a wisecrack or a foolish act, but I don't recall every seeing *chochem* used sarcastically. A *lamden* is indeed a scholar, but I can't see how you can constrast a *chochem* and a *lamden* in a meaningful way. In short, it's not any kind of expression that I've come across or that even makes sense to me.

I can't make heads or tales of the *hechtsuppe* etymology either. Never heard of it in Yiddish.

Comment: What about the explanation Takkat found: "poschut kochem" -> "wenig klug" (little intelligent)? It would be like a "hollow wise man" (what I made up according of your explanation), which would be a nice transliteration for "stupid guy".

Comment: _Poschut_ is a different word from the Slavic _pust_; it comes from the Hebrew and it means "plain".

Answer (score 1):

Mir erzählte ein Freund, das Wort "Pustekuchen" käme vom Polnischen "Pusta Kuchnia", was "Leere Küche" bedeutet. Diese Erklärung leuchtet mir mehr ein als die anderen, ich habe aber keine Belege dafür.

Answer (score 0):

Ja, kann nichts anders finden:

[wdr5.de](http://www.wdr5.de/sendungen/leonardo/s/d/24.06.2004-16.05/b/die-kleine-anfrage-woher-kommt-das-wort-pustekuchen.html?&cHash=2d5af07fa3&tx_rlmpflashdetection_pi1%5Bflash%5D=1)
[declever.com](http://www.declever.com/schule/schule-1-2608.html)
[kindergarten-pustekuchen.org](http://www.kindergarten-pustekuchen.org/ueber-uns/unser-name.html)
[gutefrage.net](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/pustekuchen-wo-kommt-der-begriff-her)
[de.answers.yahoo.com](http://de.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080708012803AAg8DNK)
[wissen.de](http://www.wissen.de/wde/generator/wissen/ressorts/kinder/index,page=1304822.html)
[verben.texttheater.net](http://verben.texttheater.net/forum/index.php?topic=70.0)

EDIT:
Nicht viel mehr, aber mein "Duden Deutsches Universal-Wörterbuch A-Z" fügt hinzu:
viell. nach der Wendung "jmdm. etw. pusten"

Comment: Danke für die vielen schönen Links. Diese können aber mit der Zeit unerreichbar sein. Deshalb wäre es schön, wenn Du zu jedem Link auch das passende Zitat einfügen könntest. Nur so kann Deine Antwort auch einen längeren Zeitraum überleben.

Comment: Das schon. Einige davon betreffen Diskussionen und wären deshalb schwer zu kopieren, aber na, ja. :-)