# Wissenswertes über "Fleppen"?

Tags: etymology, meaning, word-usage

**Fleppen** (Plural) ist ein umgangssprachliches(?) Synonym für Führerschein.

> Ohne "*Fleppen*" erwischt *- Nordkurier, 23.03.10*
>   Mit Alkohol, ohne *Fleppen* und Helm *- Märkische Allgemeine, 17.12.08*
>   Der darf eigentlich seit 2004 keinen Meter mehr ein Auto fahren, denn solange hat er schon keinen *Fleppen* mehr. *- Leipziger Volkszeitung, 13.12.11*

[image: fleppen weg]
*(Sächsische Zeitung, 29.02.12, S. 2 bzw. [online](http://www.sz-online.de/Nachrichten/Politik/Bei_acht_Punkten_sind_die_Fleppen_weg/articleid-3000340) mit Bezahlschranke.)*

Mir war der Begriff bisher nur aus der regionalen (Sachsen) Umgangssprache bekannt. Das Auftauchen im überregionalen Teil einer Zeitung heute lässt mich fragen, ob *Fleppen* auch anderswo bekannt sind - und überhaupt: Was ist das für ein seltsames Wort?

Eine Suche im [Presseportal](http://alt.genios.de/) lässt vermuten, dass der Begriff überwiegend im Ostmitteldeutschen Raum verwendet wird.

Was ist zur Wortherkunft zu sagen?

Bezieht sich die Bedeutung allein auf *Führerschein*?

Gibt es das Wort eigentlich nur im Plural?

Comment: Da hätte ich beim Lesen der Zeitung nicht gewusst, um was es geht, wenn da nicht das Konterfei unseres geliebten Verkehrsminister wäre - mir ist nur der umgangssprachliche Ausdruck _Lappen_ ein Begriff - ansonsten kennt [Openthesaurus](http://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/f%C3%BChrerschein) noch ein paar andere Begriffe, aber nicht _Fleppen_.

Comment: *Lappen* - das wird mit der Plastikkarte auch aussterben ... Unter "Ergebnisse" des von dir genannten Links ist übrigens auch *Fleppe* zu finden, jedoch ohne Eintrag. Im Singular kenne ich das nur im Zusammenhang "*Fleppe ziehen*": *Was ziehst du denn für eine Fleppe? - Was machst du denn für ein Gesicht?* wenn jemand enttäuscht guckt.

Comment: Du hast absolut recht - ich muss blind gewesen sein - dann gibt es also wohl das Synonym _Fleppen_ - wieder was gelernt...

Comment: @Jakob: So wie "etwas auf dem Kerbholz haben" jetzt auch bald endlich ausstirbt? Und die Kuhhaut, auf die nix mehr geht?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wie so viele Wörter kommt auch die *"Fleppe"* oder *"Flebbe"* aus dem [Rotwelsch](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2530/23).

> **Fleppe**
>   Mit Fleppe bezeichnen die Walzgesellen ihre Ausweispapiere und Bücher aller Art. So reden sie auch von der Schallerfleppe (Liederbuch). Der Begriff Fleppe komt vom eng. flap was Schlag oder Klaps bedeutet. Ursprünglich war damit ein Buch aufschlagen gemeint. <sup>[Vagapedia](https://vagapedia.wikispaces.com/Fleppe)</sup>

Über die regionale Verbreitung in Deutschland, und wie gebräuchlich der Ausdruck außerhalb der östlichen Bundesländer ist, konnte ich nichts finden. Immerhin kennt auch der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fleppe) dieses Wort. Bei uns hier in Süddeutschland habe ich es allerdings noch nie gehört.

Comment: Sieh an, der Duden - da hätte ich es gar nicht vermutet!

Comment: Ich (Berlin - Ost) kannte dieses Wort bisher nicht und hätte es auch nicht raten können... wirkt beim 1. lesen wie ein Plural auf mich trotz Artikel. Ich würd' sagen, das ist doch schon noch eher (um mal sinnlos ein paar Partikeln zu verwenden) was Regionales :)

Comment: Ostberlin? Eine Bekannte aus MOL meinte heute, dass sie das Wort auch kenne. Allerdings kommt ein Teil ihrer Familie aus Sachsen-Anhalt. Im Duden heißt es übrigens: die Fleppe; (...) Plural: die Fleppen (meist im Plural). - siehe Link von Takkat.

Comment: Das Wort ist jedenfalls in der Region Halle-Leipzig sehr geläufig (meist als "Flebbm").

Comment: Das Wort "Fleppe" (singular) is auch im Ruhrgebiet sehr geläufig ("Ich musste meine Fleppe für einen Monat abgeben").

Answer (score 3):

Ich komme aus Mecklenburg. Und bei uns hieß die Fahrerlaubnis früher auch Fleppen. Und zwar unter uns jungen Menschen (damals) ausschließlich. Führerschein war verpönt und Fahrerlaubnis zu lang und irgendwie uncool als Wort.