# Unterschied zwischen "Klamotten" und "Kleider"?

Tags: difference, noun, synonym, connotation

Mein Lehrer sagte, dass *Klamotten* ein anderes Wort für *Kleider* ist - aber gibt es einen Unterschied? Wann kann ich das Wort *Klamotten* benutzen, aber nicht *Kleider*?

Beispiele für [Klamotten](http://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=klamotten) und [Kleider](http://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=Kleider) auf Linguee.

Comment: *Kleider* ist imho old-fashioned, d.h. die Verwendung reduziert sich zumeist auf Redewendungen, wie *Kleider machen Leute* oder *sich die Kleider vom Leib reißen*. Der Begriff *Kleidung* wird häufig verwendet, nicht selten auch mit der Vorsible *Be*, wie in Sportbekleidung, und *Klamotten* ist in der heutigen Sprache der meistverwendete Begriff (was aber durchaus regional bedingt sein könnte)

Comment: [Klamotten](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kleidung%2CKleider%2CKlamotten&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) ist der am **seltensten** verwendete Begriff, weit nach *Kleidung* und *Kleider*.

Comment: @Takkat Dir ist schon bewusst, dass ich von gesprochener Sprache spreche? Sonst wäre der Hinweis auf regional auch überflüssig, wa? Klamotten ist **definitiv** der am häufigste verwendete Begriff in meiner Region. Is so, kannste nix ändern.

Comment: Nein, es war mir nicht bewusst, dass wir hier von Umgangssprache reden, dann fehlen natürlich noch die [*Anziehsachen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anziehsachen) ;)

Comment: @Em1: 'is so, kannste nix ändern' ist keine Begründung und keine Quelle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe one should say that "Kleider" can have 2 meanings in german. First it's for **everything** you wear in general. But it can also mean a special type of stuff to wear: dresses.
"Klamotten" only means something to wear in general and is very informal.

Comment: *"Kleider"* is not used for everything you wear. It is not used for underwear or coats.

Comment: Gute Zusammenfassung! +1

Answer (score 9):

#### [Kleider](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kleid)

Über der Unterwäsche getragene [Bekleidung](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bekleidung), daher auch Oberbekleidung genannt. Auch, und im Singular **ausschließlich**, ein spezielles einteiliges Kleidungsstück für Damen, das Ober- und Unterkörper bedeckt (Engl.: *"dress"*).

#### [Kleidung](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kleidung)

Synonym zu Kleider, jedoch ausschließlich im *Pluraletantum* verwendete Bezeichnung für jedwede Oberbekleidung (Engl.: *"clothing"*).

#### [Klamotten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Klamotte)

Ehemals alte oder zerschlissenen Kleidung, seit Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts ursprünglich in der Berliner Gaunersprache verwendet. Möglicherweise kommt das Wort vom [Rotwelsch](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/gibt-es-rotwelsch-mittlerweile-auch-in-der-gehobenen-sprache) *"Klabot"* <sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Klamotten&view=1)</sup>. Im Singular bedeutet es auch *"zerbrochener Ziegelstein, einfacheres Theaterstück"*. Im Pluraletantum wird es heute aber **umgangssprachlich** meist synonym für Kleidung verwendet (Beispiel: *"Ihre Freundin kaufte sich immer die teuersten Klamotten, jetzt ist sie pleite."*).

Comment: Wie interessant - die Bedeutung "Ziegelstein" ist bestimmt der Grund, dass man auch schwere, unhandliche Gegenstände als "Klamotten" bezeichnet.

Comment: Zur Bemerkung, die Einzahl von Kleid gäbe es nur für Damen - jein. Vergiss nicht das Beinkleid (anderes Wort für Hose)

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: wurde nicht vergessen, aber es geht hier um den Unterschied zwischen Kleider und Klamotten. Eine Unterscheidung von Kleider in der Bedeutung von Kleidung gegenüber der Bedeutung als Plural von Kleid ist nötig, die Behandlung von allen Komposita wie Beinkleider, Altkleider, Narrenkleid, etc. führt dann aber definitiv zu weit.

Comment: Also ich finde nicht, dass "Klamotten" absolut synonym für Kleidung verwendet. Bei "Klamotten" schwingt doch immer etwas leicht Abwertendes mit, zumindest eine eher geringe Wertschätzung.

Answer (score 5):

Als Ergänzung zur Antwort von Takkat:

**Kleider**
Im weiteren Sinn Oberbekleidung, wie von Takkat ausgeführt, jedoch nur, wenn das Wort im Plural verwendet wird.
Die Einzahl dieses Wortes ist "Kleid" und das ist ein einteliges Kleidungsstück für Damen (english "dress", "gown").

**Kleidung**
Auch: "Bekleidung". Alles was man an sichtbaren Textilien am Körper trägt. Ob man Wäsche (Unterwäsche) zur Kleidung zählen kann, ist vermutlich Definitionssache. Dasselbe gilt für Schuhe und Hüte.

**Klamotten**
Dieses Wort wird nicht im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum verwendet. In Österreich wird dieses Wort häufig als Teutonismus wahrgenommen. (Teutonismus: In Deutschland gängig, wird in Österreich aber als fremd empfunden.) Wenn es in Österreich verwendet wird, dann meinst scherzhaft oder abwertend. Durch den Einfluss bundesdeutscher Medien steigt aber, wie bei fast allen Teutonismen, auch in Österreich die Häufigkeit des Gebrauchs des Wortes.

**Gewand (singular)**
Das ist das österreichische und süddeutsche Gegenstück zu den eher Berlinerischen Klamotten. Dieses Wort ist im österreichischen Deutsch ein Vokabel der Hochsprache, im deutschen Deutsch hat es hingegen den Status eines Dialekt-Wortes.

**Gewänder (plural)**
Im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum in Verwendung. Damit bezeichnet man besonders kostbare Kleidungsstücke: Ein König hüllt sich in teure Gewänder.

Comment: *Gewänder* höre ich nur in Märchen; und da Deutschland keinen König hat, kann ich dir versichern, dass das Wort mit Sicherheit nicht im *ganzen* deutschen Sprachraum in Verwendung ist. // *Gewand* klingt für mich übrigens auch sehr *geschwollen*, aber gut zu wissen, dass es im Süden üblich ist; das erspart mir den Lachkrampf, wenn ich es dann mal hören sollte -> "Klamotten ist eindeutig das schönere Wort"

Comment: @Em1 Zumindest als Umschreibung für eine Wiederauflage/Wiederentdeckung eines älteren Produkts oder Prinzips ist es aber IMHO noch recht weit verbreitet: "Altes XYZ in neuem Gewand"

Answer (score 5):

**Klamotten** ist umgangssprachlich. Es ist der im Alltagsgebrauch häufigste und verbreitetste Begriff für Kleidung, allerdings in formellen Situationen unpassend. Sprecher älter als ca. 50 Jahre sagen nicht *Klamotten*, sie sprechen von *Kleidung*. *Klamotten* wird in Österreich und der Schweiz nicht verwendet. In der Schweiz ist *Kleider* der äquivalente Begriff (s.u.).

**Kleidung** ist der standardsprachliche Begriff, wirkt aber leicht formell und ist eher bei älteren Sprechern verbreitet. Im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch spezifizieren die meisten Sprecher die Kleidungsstücke oder implizieren die Kleidung nur:

- "Ich ziehe mich schnell an." (keine explizite Nennung der Kleidung)
- "Ich kauf mir was zum Anziehen." (Substantivierung des
  Verwendungszwecks)
- "Ich gehe einkaufen. Ich brauche eine neue Hose." (Nennung des
  Kleidungsstücks)

Insbesondere die Substantivierung des Verwendungszwecks – **(etwas) zum Anziehen** – ist stark verbreitet. Sie ist stilitisch neutral (einerseits nicht umgangssprachlich und andererseits nicht formell) und dadurch für alle Situtation geeignet.

**Kleider** ist in der Bedeutung "Kleidung" weniger gebräuchlich und wird eher von älteren Sprechern als weniger formelles Synonym von *Kleidung* verwendet. Es impliziert doch zu stark ein bestimmtes Kleidungsstück (weibliche Oberbekleidung aus Oberteil und Rock), was leicht zu Missverständnissen führt. *Kleid* (auch im Singular) mit der Bedeutung "Kleidung" ist vor allem in Süddeutschland gebräuchlich und in der Schweiz ein allgemein gebräuchlicher Begriff.

In den Dialekten gibt es weitere Begriffe, die regional gebräuchlicher sein können, als die oben genannten standard- und umgangssprachlichen Formen (Bsp. *Hääs* im Schwäbischen und Schweizerdeutschen oder *Gewand* im Bairischen und Österreichischen [nicht zu verwechseln mit dem altertümlichen, gehobenen, standardsprachlichen *Gewand*, das teilweise eine andere Bedeutung hat]).

Comment: Zur Komplettierung deiner schönen Liste: ein weiterer umgangssprachlich häufig genommener Begriff für Kleidung ist ***"meine/deine Sachen"***.

Comment: @Takkat Sehr schön, stimmt genau. Hab ich vergessen :-)

Comment: Du kannst es ja noch einbauen ;)

Comment: Wollte ich gerade, war dann aber unsicher. Findest du auch, dass man "Sachen" für Kleidung nur benutzt, während man sie gerade nicht trägt? Z.B. ich war baden, will mich jetzt anziehen und entdecke, dass meine Kleidung nass gespritzt wurde: "Meine Sachen sind ja ganz nass!" Aber wenn ich sie anhabe, geht das nicht: "Wie gefallen dir meine neuen Sachen?" (dreht sich dabei vor dem Betachter) -- das klingt für mich falsch. Was denkst du?

Comment: Das scheint ziemlich richtig. Ich bin mir (fast) sicher dass es ungebräuchlich ist, von angezogenen "Sachen" zu reden. Hoffe ich täusche mich da nicht.

Comment: Hab hier eine neue Frage gestellt: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/wann-kann-man-sachen-fur-kleidung-sagen

Answer (score 3):

Vielleicht noch eine weitere Ergänzung für bestimmte Kontexte:

> "etwas zum Anziehen"

Meines Erachtens ist das der am häufigsten verwendete Ausdruck in Kontexten wie:

> "Ich habe nichts zum Anziehen." - *"I don't have anything to wear (for
>   this occasion)."*
>
> "Ich muss mir etwas zum Anziehen kaufen." - *"I'll have to go shopping
>   (for clothes)."*
>
> "Hast du genug zum Anziehen eingepackt?" - *"Did you pack enough
>   clothes?"*