# Wann kann man "Sachen" für "Kleidung" sagen?

Tags: style, connotation

In manchen Situationen kann man "Sachen" für Kleidung sagen, in anderen nicht.

**Gebräuchlich** (?):

> a) Ich bin beim Baden, meine Kleidung liegt irgendwo, ich will sie
>   anziehen, entdecke aber, dass sie nass geworden ist: "Meine Sachen
>   sind ja ganz nass!"
>
> b) Mein kleines Kind ist vom Essen im Gesicht und an den Händen ganz
>   verschmiert, kommt zu mir und fasst mich an. Ich schiebe es mit den
>   Worten von mir: "Mach meine Sachen nicht schmutzig!"
>
> c) Ich habe die Wäche abgehängt und zusammengelegt, da klingelt ein
>   Freund an der Tür und bittet mich runter. Ich antworte: "Kleinen
>   Moment, ich muss noch schnell meine Sachen in den Schrank legen."

**Ungebräuchlich** (?):

> d) Ich habe neue Kleidung und führe sie meiner Freundin vor: "Wie
>   gefallen dir meine neuen Sachen?"

Mir scheint, dass man "Sachen" entweder nur dann verwendet, wenn man die Kleidung nicht trägt (a und vielleicht c) oder wenn es um ihren Zustand geht (a und b).

Gibt es da eine Regelhaftigkeit in der Verwendung?

Comment: Imho kannst du prinzipiell immer deine Kleidung durch *Sachen* oder *Zeugs* (z.b. Badezeugs) ersetzen, solange wie der Kontext klar ist. Immerhin können beide Wörter quasi alles bedeuten. In c) z.b. Spielsachen, in b) deine Bastelsachen. - In d) finde ich es übrigens nicht ungebräuchlich, nicht selten ist aber Kleidung hier nur eine Untermenge: "Ich hab ein paar neue Sachen gekauft; hier (*kram*), wie findest du das Hemd?"

Comment: Meines Erachtens sagt man "Sachen" dann, wenn es nicht wirklich darauf ankommt, dass es Kleidung ist. "Du hast meine Sachen ganz nass gemacht!" - mich stört, dass das Zeug nass ist, unabhängig davon, dass es sich (ausschließlich oder größtenteils) um Kleidung handelt. "Beim Empfang solltest du auf deine Kleidung achten." Hier ist es wesentlich, dass es sich um die Kleidung handelt, die ordentlich aussehen sollte (bei "solltest du auf deine Sachen achten" würde ich eher an eine Warnung vor Taschendieben denken).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eine generelle Ungebräuchlichkeit des Wortes `Sachen` für `Kleidung` in der unter d) geschilderten Situation ist mir nicht geläufig.

`Sachen` bezeichnet meines Erachtens die Gesamtheit der Kleidung oder eine nicht näher bestimmte Teilmenge davon. In den Situationen a), b) und c) ist dies der Fall.

Daher würde ich `Sachen` in Situation d) auch benutzen, wenn ich nicht ein bestimmtes Kleidungsstück, sondern mehrere (oder gar alle) der gezeigten Kleidungsstücke meine. - Wollte ich eines herausstellen, würde ich es in dieser Situation immer benennen: "Wie findest Du mein neues Hemd [meinen Hut, meine Krawatte]?"