# die Bekleidung und die Kleidung

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, german-to-english

I know that *die Kleidung* is derived from *kleiden* by removing -en and adding ung. Therefore, I expect *die Bekleidung* is derived from *bekleiden*. However, it seems that this word is not so common.

I want to know

1. whether *bekleiden* is a commonly used word
2. the difference between the meaning of *bekleiden* and that of *kleiden*
3. the difference between the meaning of *die Bekleidung* and that of *die Kleidung*

Thanks so much

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5108/16660

Comment: _Kleidung_ and _kleiden_ is more about what you wear, _Bekleidung_ and _bekleiden_ rather highlights that you are wearing anything at all.

Comment: Bitte nur immer eine Frage auf einmal. Man kann leicht einen der Teile gut beantworten ohne andere gut zu beantworten. Welche Antwort willst Du dann akzeptieren? Diese Regel ist keine Schikane sondern sinnvoll.

Answer (score 5):

*Bekleidung* is most commonly used when referring to clothing as *goods* ("Bekleidungshandel", "Bekleidungsgeschäft", "Bekleidungsindustrie",...), while *Kleidung* rather refers to the functional aspects of clothing (covering people) - "Kleidungsstil", "Berufskleidung", "Alltagskleidung". The distinction is, however, not very sharp and there is a lot of overlap.

Similarly, *sich kleiden* and *sich bekleiden* **can** be used as synonyms.

"Ein Amt bekleiden" does only work with "bekleiden".

Answer (score 4):

[Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bekleidung) lists `Kleidung` as one description of the meaning for `Bekleidung`, so, they should be synonymous in those contexts.

`Bekleidung` can also mean the paneling of of a wall, but I think in this context `Verkleidung` is used more often.

`Bekleiden` is rarely used with the same meaning as `kleiden`. Most of the time it is used for positions.

> Er bekleidet das Amt des Bürgermeisters.

But they can be synonymous as well.