# Woher kommt das Wort "abnippeln"?

Tags: etymology, slang

Gibt es dazu eine gesicherte Etymologie?

Answer (score 13):

Wahrscheinlich entstammt *"abnibbeln"* wie so manche umganggsprachliche Wörter aus dem [Rotwelsch](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/gibt-es-rotwelsch-mittlerweile-auch-in-der-gehobenen-sprache). Hierzu folgende Referenzen:

- [Franka Birkholz: Rotwelsch - Die geheime Sprache sozialer Außenseiter:](http://books.google.de/books?id=MwaO3pZ-tp4C&pg=PA38&dq=abnibbeln)

  > **abnibbeln** - sterben (jidd. *niwel* - verwelkt)
- [Di Gojim: Kleines jiddisches Glossar:](http://www.di-gojim.de/begriffe.html)

  > **abnibbeln** - hebräisch *nawol* = welken

---

Denkbar ist auch die Herkunft von dem veralteten Verb *[nibeln](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GN03610)* für neblig werden. Hier gäbe es eine Bedeutungsanalogie zu *erbleichen*, *verbleichen*, *verscheiden*, die seltene Synonyme für *sterben* sind. Eine Referenz dafür habe ich aber aber nicht.

Comment: So ähnlich *sterben* zu *erstarren*, zw. en. *starve*; *darben* vielleicht zu *dürre*; *Skelett* zu Gr. σκέλλεσθαι ‘vertrocknen, verdorren, hinsiechen, ermatten, erhärten, austrocknen, ausdörren’. Allerdings ist Ost-Jiddisch im Ursprung eine deutsche Sprache mit Hebräischen Anleihen, da b zu jidd. w wird, und nicht andersrum, kann das nicht die Lösung sein (Hebräisch heißt hebräisch *Ivrit*). I vrite a lot of nonsense, too, so ...

Comment: Allerdings verhält sich *welken* zu *wolkig* (so ein Hinweis im Wiktionary) gar ähnlich wie *Nebel* zu *nibeln*, und erfährt so ohne "Bedeutungsanalogie" eine Bedeutung als Metapher für das *Verwittern*. Zwar von Pflanzen, und erst in Folge dessen von Menschen. Übrigens scheint es die Hebräische Wurzel tatsächlich zu geben, s. [נבילה](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94), [נבל](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/נבל), wobei "Wurzel" etwas hochgegriffen ist, s. bspw. נבחר und נָבִיא, נִבֵּא, dot dot dot

Answer (score 7):

Ich bezweifle, dass du eine "gesicherte" Wortherkunft finden wirst. Das Wort ist ausschließlich Umgangssprache. Viele Dictionaries kennen das Wort gar nicht erst. In Corpora finden sich wenige bis gar keine Einträge.

Das macht es sehr schwierig zu sagen, wann das Wort zuerst verwendet wurde und wie es damals gedeutet wurde. In welchem Kontext wurde es denn ursprünglich verwendet. Oder hatte das Wort von Anfang an die Bedeutung, welche es heute hat.

Die Theorie des Dudens zur Herkunft von *[abnibbeln](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abnibbeln)* halte ich daher für recht wahrscheinlich. Insbesondere hinsichtlich der Überlegung, wenn du nur lang genug *nibbelst*, bleibt am Ende nichts mehr übrig. Und von dort eine Übertragung zum Tod ist nicht mehr allzu fern. Und wenn ich mich weit aus dem Fenster lehnen darf, würde ich sagen, dass am Anfang von einem Tier die Rede war, an dem *genibbelt* wurde. Aber selbst wenn es so wäre, könnte ich es nicht belegen.

> Herkunft ungeklärt; vielleicht zu niederdeutsch nibbeln = mit den Lippen, Zähnen kleine Stücke von etwas lösen

Das Wort *abnippeln* ist übrigens, soweit ich weiß, nicht überall geläufig. Auch die Schreibweise scheint nicht mal eingängig zu sein. Da ich es mit einem deutlichen p-Laut ausspreche, käme ich nicht auf die Idee das Wort mit b zu schreiben, wie es der Duden kennt. Im Norddeutschen scheint es aber mit relativ softem b-Laut gesprochen zu werden. Aber als Nicht-Norddeutscher ist das nur eine Impression.

Comment: Also ich kenne abnippeln mit p-Laut, und abnibbeln mit b-Laut, wobei sie nicht dasselbe bedeuten. Abnippeln bedeutet sterben und abnibbeln bedeutet knabbern. Aber vielleicht ist diese Differenzierung nur regional (Rheinland).

Comment: im Norden Deutschens gilt das Elbe wie wohl bei [Dussel](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58025/orthography-voiced-sonorant-after-short-vowel-dusselig) auch

Answer (score 2):

Ein Nippel ist ein Verbindungsstück für Rohre oder auch Speichen. Wenn ich abnippele, löst sich die Verbindung zum Rest.

Comment: Das is doch nich etwa Meister Röhrichs *Schnüffelstück*? Siehe auch Holländisch *sneuvelen* "omkomen", "to die in battle", Englisch *snuff*, bzw. englisch *snuff*. Was du da beschreibst klingt wie eine [Muffe](https://dwds.de/wb/Muffe).

Answer (score 0):

Um all den mehr oder weniger plausiblen Spekulationen noch eine Privatetymologie hinzuzufügen: Ich sehe eine lautliche Ähnlichkeit zwischen Nippel und Nippes. Nippes ist ja unbedeutender Kleinkram. Wenn ich alte Wendungen wie "alles ist eitel" auf das irdische Leben beziehe, könnte "abnippeln" auch scherzhaft für "dem Irdischen entsagen/entkommen" stehen.

Answer (score -2):

Eine der einschlägigen protoindoeuropäischen Wortwurzeln für das Ableben liegt in *necro-* vor.

Auf Hochdeutsch müsste die Entsprechung homophon zu *nah, nach, genug* sein, Nullstufig *ung-*, vgl. englisch *Yngvi*.

- Um auf Umwegen zu *abnippeln* zu kommen, sei zuerst auf umgangangsprachliches *jmd. aufknöpfen* verwiesen. Da *Knopf*, *Knüppel* und etliches mehr als lautmalerische Bildungen verstanden werden können, erübrigt sich die genauere phonologische Analyse. Die Lemma bei Pfeifer und Kluge sind dahingehen leider konfus.
- Einen Hinweis könnte zuerst *nuckeln* nebst *Nippel* geben, bzw. *Schnuller*, ebenso *(ein Bier) schnullern*, so wie ich zu [*snack*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69618/streusel-schnecke-oder-schneck) schon an anderer Stelle geschrieben habe, was weiterhin ungeklärt bleibt. Dies deutet auf einen ungeklärten wechsel *K / *P hin, der phonetisch etwa *tough* "taff" entsprechen dürfte.
- Aus semantischer Sicht wiederum passend gibt es *neppen*, en. *kidnap, nab*, bzw. *to nick*.

Allerdings liegt die Vermutung nahe, dass [*neḱ-](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/ne%E1%B8%B1-) "to disappear, perrish" selbst einer internen Ableitung bedarf, bspw. mit *ne "not", die sich in weiterführenden Vergleichen wiederspiegeln dürfte. Hinweise auf Volksetymologien, die diesen Zusammenhang erhellen mögen, werden dankend angenommen.

Übrigens stehen die "Rotwelschen" Belege (s. o. @Takkat) dem nicht entgegen, insoweit Jiddisch eine aus dem Altdeutschen hervorgegangen Mischsprache ist. Genaueres ist bei dem aktuellen Wissensstand in diesem Fall nicht zu erwarten (wie @Takkat letztendlich zugibt).

**PS:** Niederländisch *sneven* "omkomen [umkommen]" wäre im Vergleich mit Mittelhochdeutsch *sneben, snaben* heranzuziehen. Siehe dazu de Vries:

> Die germanischen Wurzeln **snaðōn, snuðōn* ["schneiden"] sind nicht eindeutig. Sicherlich nicht [...] aus einer indoeuropäischen Wurzel **(s)kneu-*, wozu althochdeutsch *hniuwan* "stoßen, aufreiben", altnordisch *hnøggva* "schlagen, stoßen" zu zählen wären. Eher eine rein germanische Form, die man mit der Grupper um *schnappen* [snappen] behandeln kann. [*J. de Vries (1971), Nederlands Etymologisch Woordenboek, Leiden. [https://www.etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/sneven] Übersetzt aus dem Niederländischen von mir, @vectory, mithilfe online Übersetzung*]

Andere Verweise bei etymologiebank sprechen sich deutlich für Lautmalerei aus: "de klankschilderende groep woorden met anlautend sn, zoals *snijden, snavel, snip*, met grondbetekenis ‘snijden, scherp’", "Een van de klankexpressieve sn-woorden". Die neueste Aufarbeitung des Niederländischen dank Philippa *et al.* (a.a.O.) lässt das Wort wohlgemerkt außen vor. Deutsche Wörterbücher sehen das sicherlich ähnlich.

Weil *onomatopoeia* nicht weiterführen, bedarf diese Ansicht weiterer Bemerkungen.

- *nibben* "mit den Lippen, Zähnen kleine Stücke von etwas lösen" (s. o. @Em1) gehört zu deutsch *(am Glas) nippen*, was wiederum den oben angesetzten Bedeutungswandel bestätigt, vgl. *nach Luft schnappen*, *schnabulieren* etc.

  - Wiktionary rekonstruiert urgermanisch **hnippōną.* "to pinch", "Likely related to **knīpaną*" (en.WT: [**hnīpaną*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/hn%C4%ABpan%C4%85)), ohne den Zusammenhang mit einem äußerst fragwürdigen ga-Präfix zu erkennen, vgl. allemanisch *gsë* "sehen" (en.WT: [*gasehwaną](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/gasehwan%C4%85), [wér kseenisch de](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/w%C3%A9r_kseenisch_de)).
  - Dieser Ansatz passt im Prinzip auch zum "Verbindungsstück für Rohre oder auch Speichen" (s. o. @user54646); ist ohne weiteres leider unklar. Vgl. *abdrücken, abdichten, abschließen*, nicht etwa *abschüsseln*, zumal allenfalls im Gegensatz zu *anschließen* von lösen die Rede sein kann, in der Regel jedoch das Gegenteil gemeint ist (mag auch regionale Unterschiede geben). Da wäre höchsten an *abnabeln* zu denken, wobei die Nabelschnur durch zudrücken zertrennt wird.
- **(s)knew-* fügt sich entsprechend ins Bild mit *hnawwaz "tight; narrow; sparse", doch sind die unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen nicht eindeutig, die diese Wurzel fortsetzen (s. [hnøggr](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hn%C3%B8ggr), [nøgga](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hn%C3%B8ggr) usw.; NB: Lindeman's Ordbok hat es nicht). Ist vielleicht **kes-* gemeint, vgl. *snøggr* (en.WT: [**ksnew-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/ksnew-))?
- vergleichbar erscheint ohnehin *neigen*, vgl. gothisch *hnaiws*, s. *hnaiwijaną, "variant form of *hnaigijaną" (en.WT: ); auch wieder ein Sonderfall.
- im Old Frisian Etymological Dictionary (Boutkan, Siebinga (2005)) finde ich nichts dergleichen, wenngleich weiteres zu Vermutungen gereicht.

Deshalb bleibt der Ansatz mit *neḱ- am wahrscheinlichsten.

**PPS**: Außerdem werden Tocharisch A *oṅk* B *eṅkwe* "man" im Sinne von *sterblicher* irgendwie auf *neḱ- zurückgeführt. Ohne weitere Bestätigung dürfte o-stufig "so ein Nappel" deshalb dahingestellt bleiben, auch wegen der eingangserwähnten Problematik um *Knopp*, *Knabe* etc.

Bemerkenswert ist dies weil die Sagengestalten der *Nibelungen* als Bewohner des Erdreichs charakterisiert werden, also vermutlich sterblich. Soweit dieser Name eher mit *Nebel* verglichen wurde, schließt sich zumindest der Kreis mit *nibeln* (s.o. @Takkat).

**Summasumarum** bedeutet das, die Bedeutung müsste die letzten Jahrhunderte über relativ stabil geblieben sein, während der Lautwandel angesichts ie. *neḱ-insoweit als irregulär anzusehen ist und schriftliche Belege im Fall von Tabuthemen kaum zu erwarten sind. Sicher ist das also nicht.

Comment: Und wenn der Code of Conduct zulässt, dass miserable Antworten gepostet werden, aber verbietet, dass man  pseudowissenschaftliches Geschwafel als pseudowissenschaftliches Geschwafel bezeichnet, dann sollte der Code of Conduct überarbeitet werden.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142514/discussion-between-jonathan-scholbach-and-alina).

Comment: Woher nimmst du die Zeit und die Energie? Ich habe deine Antwort bisher nicht runtergewählt, aber die Unterstellung in deinem Kommentar hier finde ich absolut unangebracht.

Comment: Ich habe umfängliche Suchen um weitere Vergleiche betrieben. Leider sind meine Notizen nicht sortiert. Im schweizer jiddisch steht *nahen* oder so für "sterben" nebst *niften*. Süd-Hessisch *abnabben* "selbstmord begehen". Ein Kollege kennt tatsächlich *Nübbel* oder so als Synonym für *Muffe*, s. a. SHess. -Scheibe. Althaus: *neppen* könnte auch jiddisches Rotwelsch sein. Zu Nl. *sneven* habe ich nichts weiter als den niederdeutschen Beleg gefunden. Wegen der jiddischen Tangente, der möglichen Wortspiele, der als irregulär / regional anzunehmenden Lautwandel und der mangelhaften Unterstützung.