# Etymologie des Wortes "abknibbeln"

Tags: etymology

In Anlehnung an die Frage [Woher kommt das Wort “abnippeln”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/woher-kommt-das-wort-abnippeln) interessiert mich die Herkunft des Wortes "abknibbeln", welches ich seit meiner Kindheit im Ruhrgebiet kenne und auch häufig verwende.

Einen direkten Bezug zu "abnippeln/abnibbeln" erkenne ich, zumindest von der Verwendung des Begriffes, nicht. Kann mir jemand die Etymologie dieses Wortes näher bringen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das Wort leitet sich aus dem niederdeutschen *[knippen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK08991)* her:

> **3)** *nd.* mit der schere oder den nägeln abstutzen, mit der zange kurz abkneipen. <sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK08991)</sup>

Diese Bedeutung ist auch im niederländischen [afknippen](http://translate.google.de/#nl/en/afknippen) enthalten. Die Verschiebung von *"p"* nach *"b*" ist regional bedingt. Mit einer *"-el"*-Suffigierung wird hier ein Diminutiv zu *knippen* gebildet.

Siehe auch Duden: [knibbeln](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/knibbeln)