# orthography: voiced sonorant after short vowel, "dusselig"

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, consonant-sounds

For the unvoiced sonorant /s/ we have either of both:

- ß marking /s/ after long vowels

  - "Fuß", "in maßen"
- double-s to mark /s/ after short vowels

  - "Fluss", "in Massen"

Whereas for the voiced sonorant /z/ we have

- single s after long vowels

  - "Fusion", "Masern"

  never mind the pronounciation oblivious spelling of *Mus* /s/ and several other cases of terminal devoicing (Auslautverhärtung) and loanwords (viz *mousse*).

But I see no unambiguous notation for ...

- ... voicing after short vowels

  - "Jeder *Dussel* hat'n *Fussel*", "krisselig", or loanwords like "Puzzle"

  This  is relatively rare in German maybe, the qualities of *Dussel* would depend on dialect. *Fussel* implies English *fuzzy* (but cp. *Fitzelchen*, *Fetzen*). Hence I thought *Dussel* might belong with En. *dazzle, bedazzle* (properly compared to *dösen* "snooze"?), if not *stutzig*, *verdutzt*. But this is not an etymology question.

**What's up with the spelling** of voiced dental sonorants after nominally short vowels, does such a sound quality just not exist in Modern High German, or do we pretend it weren't there?

Comment: I'm sure this must be a duplicate, but the search showed none.

Comment: I can't give a reference, but I suspect that your conjecture that the sound quality does not exist in Modern High German is correct. In fact, all the examples I can think of look like dialectal words imported from Low German to me.

Comment: At least here in South-Western Germany, it seems that "Dussel" is spoken with an unvoiced 's'. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dussel) also indicates the pronunciation as "[ˈdʊsl̩]", not "[ˈdʊzl̩]". I am not convinced there is an actual difference in pronunciation for a select couple of words, as, from the few speakers from Northern Germany that I know who do pronounce "Dussel" with a voiced 's' after a short vowel, they do the same thing for virtually any 'ss' occurrence I can think of - "quasseln", "vermasseln", "Ossi", "vermissen", "müsse" ... thus, it seems more like a ...

Comment: ... general dialect-based pronunciation difference for 'ss' to me.

Comment: quatsch nicht dusselig, I know how I say *müssen*, that is sharp as a nail. There's even *Dusel* for "luck", guess that's "dumb luck". No offense (offence?) yeah I might be observing different dialects coming together, with a natural tendency to hear dialectal words in a dialectal accent more often, but I'm not going to argue about purity of hyper german dialect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Lenis consonants normally preceded by long vowels

High German has a strong tendency that lenis consonants are preceded long vowels (or diphthongs, which count as long vowels in this regard). This is because short vowels followed by lenis consonants were lengthened, cf. Middle High German *lësen* vs. modern standard German *lesen* ‘to read’:

> lësen [ˈlɛsən] → lesen [ˈleːzen]

Words with short vowels followed by lenis consonants are loans from Low German or from other languages that occured after this lengthening had occured, e.g. «Buddel» ‘bottle’, «Flagge» ‘flag’, «schwabbeln» ‘to wobble’, «Dussel» ‘dimwit’, «Puzzle» ‘jigsaw puzzle’, «Schlamassel» ‘shemozzle’.

### Consonant pronunciation not affected by doubling

Almost all German consonant letters are pronounced the same whether or not they are doubled. What changes is not the pronunciation of the doubled consonant, but of the preceding vowel (this is the same in English or Dutch):

> Schafe [ˈʃaːfə] ‘sheep’ – schaffe [ˈʃafə] ‘create’
>
> Stele [ˈʃteːlə] ‘stele’ – Stelle [ˈʃtɛlə] ‘place’
>
> Rate [ˈraːtə] ‘rate’ – Ratte [ˈratə] ‘rat’

Historically, this used to be different. Doubled consonants used to be pronounced longer in Middle High German. After short vowels followed by lenis (short) consonants had been lengthened and after consonant length had been lost, the doubling of consonants has taken on a new meaning: it no longer means a long pronunciation of the consonant itself, but a short pronunciation of the preceding vowel.

### Doubling of S affects pronunciation

The letter S is different from all other German consonant letters. When it is doubled, its own pronunciation changes (this is often the case in English as well):

> Hase [ˈhaːzə] ‘hare’ – hasse [ˈhasə] ‘(I) hate’

Here we see that the single ⟨s⟩ is pronounced as a lenis [z], whereas the doubled ⟨ss⟩ is pronounced as a fortis [s]. Now in loans like «Dussel», this is a problem: we have two orthographic rules that contradict each other:

1. A short vowel must be followed by a doubled consonant.
2. A doubled ⟨ss⟩ is a fortis [s], not a lenis [z].

Apparently, the first rule wins over the second one, since we spell the word with ⟨ss⟩ in spite of the lenis [z].

### Why is S different from other consonants?

(This section is speculative.)

It is surprising that S is the only German consonant pronounced different when doubled. This is especially striking when we consider the difference from F. Both F and S are similar sounds that have comparable histories. Yet the pronunciation difference between FF and F was lost:

> hûfen → Hauffen → Haufen ‘heap’
>
> snûven → schnaufen ‘to snuffle’

By contrast, the pronunciation difference between SS and S has been kept:

> heizer → heiszer → heißer ‘hotter’
>
> heiser → heiser ‘hoarse’

I do not know the reason. Here are some factors that might be considered:

- It is common in neighbouring languages that ⟨s⟩ is voiced [z], whereas ⟨ss⟩ is voiceless [s].
- There is no other candidate for writing lenis [z] in German (⟨z⟩ stands for [ts]). This is different from F, where ⟨w⟩ has become the voiced counterpart.
- In the actual pronunciation of many speakers, the contrast might not exist at all: they will pronounce «heißer» exactly like «heiser», or they will rhyme «Diskussion» with «Konfusion». The differentiation might be a learned spelling pronunciation.
- A factor that might have helped in retaining the different pronunciation of ⟨ss⟩ might be the existence of the SZ ligature in the fraktur script, from which the modern letter ⟨ß⟩ was derived in the 1902 spelling reform.