# Why "schieben" guards "Wache"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, idiom

The expression "Wacheschieben" is well-known to native speakers. It's synonymous to "Wachestehen".

I just realized that this word can be confusing to language learners.

> Ich habe vier Wochen hintereinander jeden Sonntag Wache geschoben.

The resulting question is: *what does it mean to "push", in this case?*

Same applies to, for instance, "Nachtschicht schieben". To push[sic] night shift?

Well, all I can say is that *schieben* in *Wacheschieben* has nothing to do with *to push*. (Though, *to push* has quite a huge set of meanings so I wouldn't be surprised if a similar sense is covered by the English word as well.)
I did a quick search, but the information I gained from Grimmsche Wörterbuch, DWDS, Duden and Wiktionary were more than just disappointing. Most of them do not contain a definition, let alone some hints on the etymology.
So the question that raised: what does *schieben* mean in this context? Where does it come from?

The only idea I can come up with is that it is related to definition 3 in [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schieben):

> [3] jemand für etwas verantwortlich machen
>
> > Sie schoben die ganze Schuld auf ihren Vorgesetzten.

When someone is in duty, the responsibility is "*pushed at him*".
However, this appears to be unlikely to me. So, again: why do we say that?

Comment: It comes from the Old German and has become naturalized...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Wie viele entstammt auch die Wendung "Wache schieben" der Gaunersprache, [Rotwelsch](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/gibt-es-rotwelsch-mittlerweile-auch-in-der-gehobenen-sprache).

Es soll aus dem jiddischen *[scheffen](http://books.google.de/books?id=Kcy_D3HtY2AC&lpg=PA1252&ots=DU3yrykAyY&dq=rotwelsch%20scheffen&pg=PA1252#v=onepage&q=rotwelsch%20scheffen&f=false)* (bilden, machen, tun, stellen, bleiben) entstanden sein und findet sich auch im Ausdruck *Kohldampf schieben* wieder.

Referenz:
[Geolino: Kohldampf schieben](http://www.geo.de/GEOlino/mensch/redewendungen/deutsch/kohldampf-schieben-51552.html)

Comment: Hat das dann auch mit "schaffen" zu tun, oder ist das eine zufällige Ähnlichkeit?

Comment: Nein, das ist nicht zufällig. Das jiddische *scheffen* leitet sich offenbar auch aus dem althochdeutschen *skephen* her.

Answer (score 2):

It's point 3 in [DWDS](http://dwds.de/?qu=schieben):

> schieben: (3) salopp, abwertend träge, in nachlässiger Haltung, mit auf
>   dem Boden schleifenden Füßen gehen ist durch den Saal schieben er hat
>   nie gelernt, anständig zu gehen, er ist immer nur geschoben

Comment: »Schieben« hat zwar auch diese Bedeutung, aber ich bezweifle, dass das etwas mit »Wache schieben« zu tun hat, zumal man beim Wache schieben nicht notwendigerweise gehen muss. Man steht mehr als man geht. Außerdem ist »schieben« in »Wache schieben« ein transitives Verb (man schiebt etwas, nämlich die Wache), während das von dir vorgeschlagene Verb intransitiv ist. Denn dein Verb wird so verwendet: »Georg schiebt durch den Saal«, nicht jedoch so : »Georg schiebt *etwas* durch den Saal«. Diese zweite Variante bedeutet etwas anderes als beim Gehen mit den Füßen zu schleifen.

Answer (score 2):

In der militärischen Redewendung "Wache schieben" haben wir es nicht mit dem normalen Verb schieben zu tun, wie es zum Beispiel in "eine Schubkarre schieben" gebraucht wird.
Es mag vielleicht aus dem Rotwelschen kommen oder woanders her. Auch für Deutsche hat "schieben" seinen Sinn verloren und ist ein reines Füllverb geworden für "Wachdienst haben".
Im militärischen und im Marinebereich gibt es allerhand verdrehte Redewendungen und Ausdrücke, die dunkel geworden sind, das heißt, man weiß nicht mehr, warum man so sagt, und ihre Herkunft ist nicht mehr einwandfrei zu klären.