# What is the origin of "Alles Paletti"?

Tags: etymology

I know what it means, but where did it come from?

Was it [the 1985 movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088698/)? Or was the phrase in use previously?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was used earlier — Google Books has [one source dating from 1973](https://books.google.de/books?id=FtZNAAAAYAAJ&q=%22alles%20paletti%22&dq=%22alles%20paletti%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CEoQ6AEwCTgKahUKEwjkmYfZttzGAhWHtxQKHYOzAuU). I assume the phrase originated between 1955 and 1973 (see the [German-Italian bilateral recruiting agreement](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anwerbeabkommen_zwischen_der_Bundesrepublik_Deutschland_und_Italien) on Wikipedia [German]). There may be sources for its usage before 1973, but I assume the phrase was first developed in oral language and later adopted in written texts.

Answer (score 15):

The etymology and origin of **paletti** in the German Language is obscure. There are some guesses it might have come from Hebrew *peletim*:

> - Die Herkunftsgeschichte von ***paletti*** geht über die hebräischen Radikale plt, *peletim* zu *Pleite*.<sup>Der Sprachdienst Vol. 28-29 1984</sup>
> - **Alles paletti:** Der beliebte Spruch wirkt so südlich heiter, dass man auf Italien als Herkunftsland tippt, doch stattdessen geht er wohl aufs Hebräische zurück. Dort gibt es eine Wurzel "plt", die "retten, in Sicherheit bringen" bedeutet und noch heute in Ifrit vorkommt als "pallet", was "Rettung" bedeutet. Es könnten jüdische Kaufleute gewesen sein, die den Ausdruck in Umlauf brachten. Sie verwendeten ihn, wenn sie ihren Besitz bei einer Pleite gerettet hatten.<sup>[Deutschlandradio Kultur](http://www.deutschlandradiokultur.de/etwas-ist-in-trockenen-tuechern.1306.de.html?dram:article_id=193518)</sup>

There are views that it might have found its way via [*Rotwelsch*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/gibt-es-rotwelsch-mittlerweile-auch-in-der-gehobenen-sprache?s=1%7C2.0856) to colloquial German, but there are no reliable references to support this.

There is nothing known of an origin from Italian but there is a temporal relationship with Italian Immigrants and the wider use of *"Alles Paletti"* in the Seventies. This may however been coincidental.

Answer (score 7):

The origin of this expression is unclear. [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/alles_paletti) says about it:

> Die Wendung ist seit dem 20. Jahrhundert bezeugt. Die Herkunft des Wortes »paletti« ist unsicher. Weder Erklärungen aus dem Italienischen noch aus dem Hebräischen können einen plausiblen Weg ins Deutsche namhaft machen.

The entry lists three sources ("Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache" and Duden, twice) that I couldn't check.

The oldest reference I've found is in [an article of "DER SPIEGEL"](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-42953743.html) from 1972, and it's a quote that, according to the context, is from 1970:

> "Nimm den Strafantrag (wegen Körperverletzung) zurück, und alles ist paletti."